# Refactor code to solve the 'Line is too long' error in rubocop

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

```
Method.create(domain_id: domain.id, type_notification: type, message: title, url: url, owner_id: self.user.id)
```

How can I reduce this line to 80 ?

Comment: What does this call do? There is no `Method.create` function in the standard [`Method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Method.html) class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd just write the call with one line per key/value:

```
Method.create(
  domain_id: domain.id, 
  type_notification: type, 
  message: title, 
  url: url, 
  owner_id: user.id
)
```

Note that the explicit reference to `self` in method calls is not idiomatic (check the [unofficial Ruby style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) for this and other useful tips).

Also, since [Method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html) is a class name already in the core, is not a good idea to have a model what that name.

Comment: Thank you @tokland self I have given because I have another local variable as user.

Comment: And If I am giving everything in broken line its contributing in number of lines. :/ #tokland

Comment: Yeah, it's a trade-off, more readable vs LOC. Of course you can break it in just two lines, but it won't be as readable, IMO.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you :) Then I will go with readability.